# Fetching messages from POP or IMAP server

Tags: ios, swift, imap, pop3, email-client

I need to fetch messages from email in my Google's Gmail account to my app in iOS (SWIFT).

Are there any framework (freeware) or simply code that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The best addvice is to look through Google's Gmail API. Here is a link to seach for messages. It is very clean and well documented so it will not take you long to do it! Just read a bit :)

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering

Comment: If I would like to login in another server this solve is not enough so Did exist another solution to make those client app?